# How to create generic popup for across the app?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create a popup which is available and controlled by across application.

so I keep the html assets in app template. and the I would like to show and hide the popup any page from the app.

I understand that, It can achivable by service. but I don't  have much idea to implement this. any one suggest me the right way?

Required is : show popup from any page, close pupup on click of close button in the popup.

here is my [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/87917e8ce7be6e2c60553401b8c7c0c1?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fpage-one)

In case of angular it can be achieved from `factory` object.

Comment: at present, I tried a way, but client require `service` approach

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do this:

1. create a component for the popup
2. create a service for the popup that that exposes methods for setting a property called "isOpen" to true/false. Other parts of the app can use the methods for opening and closing the popup.
3. Inject the popup service into the application controller
4. Add it to the application template in an `{{if popupService.isOpen}}` block

Good luck, remember to write lots of tests, make sure each part is working before you go to the next step, and remember to consult the guides often ;-)

Comment: Can you show me in twiddle I am very new to emberjs